# Enforcing Typed Relations in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design

Consider this:

```
CREATE TABLE "RTCIS"."PERSON" 
 (  "ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL,
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  "SEX" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
  "FATHERID" NUMBER(9,0) NULL,
  "MOTHERID" Number(9,0) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CK_PERSON_SEX CHECK (SEX IN ('M', 'F')),
  CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_FATHER FOREIGN KEY (FATHERID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_MOTHER FOREIGN KEY (MOTHERID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID)
 );

insert into person select 1, 'Fred',    'M', null, null from dual;
insert into person select 2, 'Charlie', 'M',    1, null from dual;
insert into person select 3, 'Doris',   'F', null,    1 from dual;
```

The 3 insert statements at the bottom all execute without problem. However, what I really would like to do is enforce that MOTHERID always points to a PERSON where SEX='F' and FATHERID always points to a PERSON where SEX='M'.

Can this be done in ORACLE without triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had various issues with materialized views as suggested by mathguy so posted the question in the [Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/13815080).

Barbara Boehmer presented a really neat way of doing this (note this excludes DDL to create the foreign key indexes but they should be added):

```
CREATE TABLE person  
(   id             NUMBER(9,0)    NOT NULL  
  , name           VARCHAR2(30)   NOT NULL  
  , gender         VARCHAR2(1)    NOT NULL  
  , fatherid       NUMBER(9,0)    NULL  
  , motherid       NUMBER(9,0)    NULL  
  , father_gender  VARCHAR2(1)    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('M') VIRTUAL  
  , mother_gender  VARCHAR2(1)    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('F') VIRTUAL  
  , CONSTRAINT     ck_person_gender    CHECK (gender IN ('M', 'F'))  
  , CONSTRAINT     pk_person           PRIMARY KEY (id)  
  , CONSTRAINT     uk_person           UNIQUE (id, gender)  
  , CONSTRAINT     fk_person_father    FOREIGN KEY (fatherid, father_gender)  
                   REFERENCES person (id, gender) ON DELETE CASCADE  
  , CONSTRAINT     fk_person_mother    FOREIGN KEY (motherid, mother_gender)  
                   REFERENCES person (id, gender) ON DELETE CASCADE  
) TABLESPACE users;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can. Not with constraints, unfortunately (check constraints can't contain subqueries), but with a materialized view. The view is updated immediately on commit; rows would be inserted in the m.v. if the parents' sex was incorrect, but the m.v. has an impossible check constraint which doesn't allow any rows to exist. Something like this; you can experiment with the concept.

```
create materialized view PERS_MV
   build immediate
   refresh fast on commit
   as select c.id
      from   person c join person p1 on c.fatherid = p1.id
                      join person p2 on c.motherid = p2.id
      where  p1.sex = 'F' or p2.sex = 'M';

alter table PERS_MV add constraint pers_mv_sex_ck (0 != 0);
```

Comment: This is a good way to solve the problem.  But you have to be careful with the materialized view query in order to enable fast refresh.  For example, ANSI joins are not supported, this is one of those rare times when you want to use the old-fashioned Oracle join syntax.